# iterate sub-sequence (chunk) of sequence within expression

Tags: python, iterator

How to iterate over a sequence, for example a `list`, and return a sub-sequence, for example a `tuple`?  Sometimes this is referred to as "chunks" or "chunking".

```
for (a, b) in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
   print('%s %s' % (a, b))
```

would print

```
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
```

The code example is not valid Python code. But it expresses what I want.

Can this be done **within one expression** (e.g. within a `lambda`)?

Answer (score 2):

Another examples how it could be done:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for (a, b) in zip(lst, lst[1::]):
   print('%s %s' % (a, b))
```

Or using `itertools`:

```
from itertools import tee

i1, i2 = tee(iter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
next(i2)
for (a, b) in zip(i1, i2):
   print('%s %s' % (a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[(l[i], l[i+1]) for i in range(len(l)-1)]
#[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this quite as you wish; an iterator references each element of the iterable exactly *once*, but you reference it twice.  The straightforward way would be

```
s = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for idx in range(1, len(s)):
    print('%s %s' % (s[i-1], s[i]))
```

If you insist on extracting from the list only once, try this:

```
a = None
for b in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
    if a:
       print('%s %s' % (a, b))
    a = b     # Save lower value for next iteration
```